# Wireless Disabled When Connected to Domain and Wired

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, lan, domain

When I'm connected to a Domain and wired lan is connected, wireless connections disappears.
Wireless Connection in Networks devices is not greyed out.

I have tried running" wmic nic where NetEnabled=False set NetEnabled=True" it doesn't show any error, but NetEnabled is not updated.

If I remove my computer from the domain this behavior will stop and I will be able to connect to wireless and wired at the same time.

Edit:
I'm asking a technical question and I'm expecting a technical answer, keep your thoughts for yourself.

Comment: Have you spoken to your domain's administrator about it?  If they've actively implemented this and you're trying to circumvent it, you may be asking for trouble. ;)

Answer (score 2):

There may be a group policy or BIOS configuration set to disable the Wi-Fi adapter whenever the system is connected to an Ethernet network. This is a security configuration which should not be tampered with if you do not own the system.

Comment: No BIOS configuration, only change if is in a domain. And no GP exists for this. So some script should be running when an event is raised.

Comment: @Vanilla - How do you know no group policy exists to disable the wireless adapater while connected to the domain?

Comment: @Vanilla Group Policy can apply changes directly to the Registry. The Registry keys which would apply this sort of configuration are notoriously undocumented and vendor-specific but, in a relatively homogenous environment, still fairly trivial to discover and set company-wide.

Comment: I checked with gpmc.msc and rsop.msc to see what policies are being applied, and I didn't found anything related to wireless. I also tried to check what registry entries are being updated when I unplug&plug the network cable and also didn't find anything related to wireless. I'm missing something but I don't know where else to look.